# Why sys.stdout (in python) doesn't have default method to restore to default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

In below programming, first we redirect all print to log files, then we close the file object and then again restort print command to interactive prompt.

```
import sys
temp = sys.stdout                 # store original stdout object for later
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w') # redirect all prints to this log file
print("testing123")               # nothing appears at interactive prompt
print("another line")             # again nothing appears. it's written to log file instead
sys.stdout.close()                # ordinary file object
sys.stdout = temp                 # restore print commands to interactive prompt
print("back to normal")           # this shows up in the interactive prompt
```

Why python doesn't support a method something like this, to restore the command to interactive mode

```
sys.stdout.default()
```

Comment: Because Python supports a whole module for logging, which you're supposed to use instead of redirecting stdout to a file.

Comment: For the same reason why a toaster oven doesn't have a button that makes it explode. Nobody needs it, and it's really not the purpose of a toaster oven.

Comment: @Aran-Fey . I am trying to understand things. But the answer you gave doesn't make me understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it almost exists: `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` reset stdout to its original value *at the start of program*.

Simply it but might not do what you want. You might *stack* `sys.stdout` redirections, and in that case, it would make sense to revert to previous redirection instead of the original one. A real use case for it in the IDLE interactive interpretor. The original stdout will be None on Windows because it is a GUI program, and will be directed to the terminal from where you started it on Linux. In either case after a redirection, you certainly do not want to use that *default* original value, but the one that was setup by IDLE.

That is the reason why you should always save the original standard output when you redirect it, and restore it when you no longer need the redirection.